# create unique id without using constructure and setters

Tags: java

```
class person {

   private  int id ;
    private String name;
    private boolean gender;

    public person() {

    }


    public AtomicLong getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(boolean gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

I want to create unique id in this class without using constructors and setters.

Comment: Please don't use meaningless text to work around the system trying to make you write a better question by giving more information. What have you already tried? Do you need this ID to be unique between multiple systems? What about multiple runs of the code? Would it be okay for it to always start with 0 and just increment?

Comment: it always start with 0 and incremented

Comment: In that case, Elliott's answer should work for you. Just be aware that if you run the program multiple times, you'll get the same IDs multiple times - so this isn't something you'd want to use for persistent data.

Answer (score 2):

To construct a `person` instance, the field *initializer* will be copied into the constructor. Assuming that's okay, you could use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and something like,

```
private static AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
private int id = ai.incrementAndGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add:

```
    private static int ID_GENERATOR = 0;
```

then, in the constructor, you will use:

```
    public person() {
        id = ID_GENERATOR++;
    }
```

Comment: Well, you wouldn't do it quite like that unless you wanted it to be non-thread-safe. Using `AtomicInteger` would be a much better idea...